# UPDATE LATEX missing file

Tags: external-files, updating

my latex is already installed but at simulation some

`tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii` file missing of `mptopdf` package, for update proxy **server adress and port no.**** and also proxy authentication **Name and password** required. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you do need to provide proxy information? Can't you just proceed without filling in those fields (assuming you do not use a proxy to connect to the internet). Also, what TeX distribution are you using?